# How do I decrease mouse cursor speed on computer?

Tags: mouse

I’ve noticed you can increase the DPI for a gaming mouse. I’ve proven that high DPI and low game settings prove for an extremely smooth gaming experience.

I’d like to know if I can use commands to set my cursor sensitivity lower than one so I can set my dpi to 16,000 but still get average speed.

Comment: what mouse do u have?

Answer (score 0):

Press Win+R to open run menu, type main.cpl, click "Pointer Options" tab, and change mouse sensitivity in Motion->"Select a pointer speed", this should do the trick. It is really easy.